# Need to get a textbox to display loop in C#

Tags: c#

Currently the task is to "Use an appropriate loop type to vary a temperature variable (which will need to be a floating point type) from the values of 5 to 23 in steps of 1.5."

but I can't calculate using the 1.5 they want as 1.5 doesn't fall under the float format.

```
private String calc(float length, float width, float depth, float surfaceArea, float volume)
        {
            float tempCount = 5;
            string output = "";
            float heatingCost;
            while (tempCount <= 23)
            {
                tempCount += 1.5;
                heatingCost = (25 - tempCount) * float.Parse(txtVolume.Text)/32500;
                output += "$" + heatingCost + "\r\n";

            }
            return output;
        }
```

This is the rest of the code

```
namespace Assessment1
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        float length = 0;
        float width = 0;
        float depth = 0;
        string output = "";

        private void label6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }


        bool validWidth(float validWidth)
        {
            string Message;
            if (validWidth >= 2 && validWidth <= 20)
            {
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                Message = "Width measuremetn is invalid \r\n Please enter a value that is greater or equal to " + 2 + " and less or equal to " + 20 + ".";
                MessageBox.Show(Message, "Data Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return false;
            }
        }

        bool validLength(float validLength)
        {
            string Message;
            if (validLength >= 5 && validLength <= 50)
            {
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                Message = "Length value is invalid.\r\n Please enter a value that is greater or equal to " + 5 + " and less or equal to " + 50 + ".";
                MessageBox.Show(Message, "Data Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return false;
            }
        }

        bool validDepth(float validDepth)
        {
            string Message;
            if (validDepth >= 2 && validDepth <= 4)
            {
                return true;

            }
            else
            {
                Message = "Depth value is invalid.\r\n Please enter a value that is greater or equal to " + 2 + " and less or equal to " + 4 + ".";
                MessageBox.Show(Message, "Data Invalid", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private String calc(float length, float width, float depth, float surfaceArea, float volume)
        {
            float tempCount = 5;
            string output = "";
            float heatingCost;
            while (tempCount <= 23)
            {
                tempCount += 1.5;
                heatingCost = (25 - tempCount) * float.Parse(txtVolume.Text)/32500;
                output += "$" + heatingCost + "\r\n";

            }
            return output;
        }

        private String tempCounter (float length, float width, float depth, float surfaceArea, float volume)
        {
            double tempCounter = 5;
            String output = "";
            while (tempCounter <= 23)
            {
                tempCounter += 1.5;
                output += tempCounter + " degrees Celcius" + "\r\n";
            }
            return output;
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            float surfaceArea;
            float volumeWater;
            float heatingCost;
            string output = "";

            surfaceArea = float.Parse(txtLength.Text) * float.Parse(txtWidth.Text);
            volumeWater = float.Parse(txtLength.Text) * float.Parse(txtWidth.Text) * float.Parse(txtAvgDepth.Text)* 1000;
            txtSurfaceArea.Text = surfaceArea.ToString();
            txtVolume.Text = volumeWater.ToString();


            if (!(validWidth(float.Parse(txtWidth.Text))))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (!(validLength(float.Parse(txtLength.Text))))
            {
                return;
            }
            if (!(validDepth(float.Parse(txtAvgDepth.Text))))
            {
                return;
            }

            if (volumeWater <= 500000)
            {
                lblCategory.Text = "Small";
            }

            if (volumeWater > 500000 && volumeWater <= 1500000)
            {
                lblCategory.Text = "Medium";
            }

            if (volumeWater > 1500000)
            {
                lblCategory.Text = "Large";
            }

            txtDollar.Text = calc(float.Parse(txtLength.Text), float.Parse(txtWidth.Text),float.Parse(txtAvgDepth.Text), float.Parse(txtSurfaceArea.Text),float.Parse(txtVolume.Text));

            txtAvgTemp.Text = tempCounter(float.Parse(txtLength.Text), float.Parse(txtWidth.Text), float.Parse(txtAvgDepth.Text), float.Parse(txtSurfaceArea.Text), float.Parse(txtVolume.Text));
        }

        private void lblDisclaimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean 1.5 doesn't fall under the float format..? If you were to look at the errors you compiler tells you, it should be obvious that floats can be declared like `float myFloat = 1.5f;`

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I can see

> ...**from** the values of 5 **to** 23 in **steps** of 1.5...

is the perfect description of the **for** loop:

```
  for (double temperature = 5.0; temperature <= 23; temperature += 1.5) {
    ...
  }
```

As for implementation:

```
  // You don´t want any input arguments
  private String Prices() {
    double value = double.Parse(txtVolume.Text); 

    // when collecting string from its parts, use StringBuilder
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (double temperature = 5.0; temperature <= 23; temperature += 1.5) {
      double cost = (25.0 - temperature) * volume / 32500.0;

      if (sb.Length > 0)
        sb.AppendLine();

      sb.Append(String.Format("${0}", cost)); 
    }

    return sb.ToString();
  }
```